# SPServices and GetListItemChanges

Tags: spservices, list-item, version-history

I'm trying to get the changes made on all items from a list using SPServices, in xml.

This is the code I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItemChanges",
        since: "2015-09-15T08:30:50-05:00",
        async: false,
        listName: "EDP Escalations",
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Request' /></ViewFields>",

        completefunc: function (xData, Status){
            console.log(xData.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

However, I'm getting this returned to me:

> Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.
>
> One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.

I don't think there's anything wrong with the fields, since I can still get xml output of the items via the GetListItems function.

What am I missing, so that I could get the xml output of all changes in all list items?

Note: I don't have SharePoint Designer, Visual Studio, or physical access to the server.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the field 'Request' is correct? That's what the error is referring to.